# Hudson Config for Mule (Cloudhub)

Tags: groovy, mule, hudson, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

I am setting up a job in hudson to build maven based mule application on SVN , uploading to artifactory and then deploy it on cloudhub.

I am able to build project and upload it to artifactory but the problem is how to deploy it on cloudhub after that.

I have groovy post build plugin but not sure what script to write in it to proceed.

Is there anyone who could give me some pointers to proceed?? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [mule-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin), it is the currently supported way to deploy to CloudHub via Maven. This a sample plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<configuration>
    <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
    <muleVersion>3.7.0</muleVersion>               <!-- This is the runtime version as it appears on the CloudHub interface -->
    <username>myUsername</username>
    <password>myPassword</password>
    <environment>Production</environment>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>deploy</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

And remember to add this to your settings.xml so Maven can find the plugin:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mule-public</id>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: In the integration tests you will find a Groovy script that does that: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-maven-plugin/blob/2.x/src/it/cloudhub/undeploy/setup.groovy

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven cloudhub-maven-plugin. Please refer details at [cloudhub-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/cloudhub-maven-plugin)

Hope this helps.